# What would be the translation for "self improvement and service"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm looking for a motto for my company. We prioritize self improvement by doing things for others, so self improvement and service would fit, but what would be the most accurate translation in latin for these words?
Thank you very much.